# rails: how to override cocoon gem helper method and call original method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cocoon-gem

i need to override a method in the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) but then call the original method. how can this be done?

```
# gem code
module Cocoon
  module ViewHelpers
    def link_to_add_association(*args, &block)
      #...stuff
    end
  end
end

# in a helper or initializer
def link_to_add_association(*args, &block)
   #...do something
   <call original method>
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# in a helper or initializer
def link_to_add_association(*args, &block)
  #...do something
  super
end
```

Comment: that doesnt work, there is no super to call. the method is not inheriting a class.

Comment: super also works for modules. Perhaps Cocon is included after all your  code is definded ... hm.... And actually you can just pick a different name for your helper

Comment: ya i think thats the only solution